# Как исправить ошибку с неожиданным типом данных?

Tags: python, pycharm

Проблема на скрине. Как убрать подсвечивания? Ошибки при выполнении кода не будет, но всё равно, выглядит не красиво. Что выдаёт pycharm при наведении:

```
Unexpected type(s): (str) Possible type(s): (int) (slice)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def db_check():
    connection = get_connection()
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM events")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        if rows:
            return rows
        else:
            db_check()


def main():
    while True:
        rows = db_check()
        for row in rows:
            id = row['id']
            message = row['message']
            event_id = row['event_id']
```

Comment: Добавьте код в виде текста, а не картинкой

Comment: @Павел добавил код

Comment: нужен также минимально воспроизводимый пример, я скопировал ваш код к себе и у меня ничего не подсвечивает (из-за того, что `get_connection()` не определено), можете попробовать с аннотациями типов поиграться, написать, какой тип функция должна возвращать

Comment: @Павел Спасибо большое. Прочитал про аннотацию типов и помогло